# How to print multiple documents using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple scanned documents that are in jpg format. I could print just one, However I don't know how to use what I have to print every single image on one page.

```
$('#prnt').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentDoc = "/Uploads" + $('#SlideContainer .actv').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1').split('/Uploads')[1];

    var Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(currentDoc));
    pwa.document.close();
    return false;

});

function ImagetoPrint(source)
{
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
            "<img style='width: 100%;' src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
}
```

This works will ...
Now, how I can print all images as one image for every single page?

```
$('#prntall').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // ???????????????
});
```

Comment: Why not put all images into one html doc and print the html doc?

Comment: @Dominik How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but you can collect all images into one node and use that.

```
    $('#prnt').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentDocList = "/Uploads" + $('#SlideContainer .actv').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1').split('/Uploads');
        const printArea = document.createElement('div');
        printArea.innerHTML = '';

        currentDocList.forEach((p) => {
            printArea.innerHTML += "<img style='width: 100%;' src='" + p + "' /><br />";
        });

        var Pagelink = "about:blank";
        var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
        pwa.document.open();
        pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(printArea));
        pwa.document.close();
        return false;
    });

    function ImagetoPrint(source) {
        return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
             + source + "</body></html>";
    }
```